# Best way to process Exif data in backend?

Tags: php, image-processing, exif

There are a lot of ways to process Exif data in backend, but they all have their problem of supporting most of the camera. The main one I came across is Perl powered  http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/. What is the major software that people use to process exif data.

It would nice if such tool has PHP interface but it doesn't really matter as long as it support command line execution

Thank you very much.

Comment: EXIF may be a standard, but it's pretty lax and has many many vendor "extensions" to store specific details not covered by the spec itself. There'll never be a single tool that can parse/read/interpret all the fields, but any app which is EXIF aware should at least be able to interpret the standard fields and display the contents of unknown ones.

Answer (score 0):

> There are a lot of ways to process Exif data in backend, but they all have their problem of supporting most of the camera.

All the camera model/vendor *specific* data is under `MakerNote` tag group. Furthermore the data usually is in a proprietary binary format.

You're on the right tracks with [**ExifTool**](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/), as it currently [supports](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/) the widest variety of cameras: Canon, Casio, FujiFilm, GE, HP, JVC/Victor, Kodak, Leaf, Minolta/Konica-Minolta, Nikon, Olympus/Epson, Panasonic/Leica, Pentax/Asahi, Reconyx, Ricoh, Samsung, Sanyo, Sigma/Foveon and Sony.

Another tool with wide camera support is OZHiker's [**PHP JPEG Metadata toolkit**](http://www.ozhiker.com/electronics/pjmt/), which might suit you better (having "PHP in its name). It [supports](http://ozhiker.com/electronics/pjmt/jpeg_info/makernotes.html): Agfa, Canon, Casio, Epson, Fujifilm, Konica/Minolta, Kyocera/Contax, Nikon, Olympus, Panasonic, Pentax/Asahi, Ricoh and Sony.

(see also a [brief comparison on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif#MakerNote_data))

I've used ExifTool a lot and can really vouch for it. It is powerful for both read **and** write operations; even when dealing with proprietary data.

Also note that ExifTool was last updated 04/2011 — while OZHiker's tool was 01/2005.